# マインクラフトforge 1.19.2　すべてのアイテムのテクスチャが反映されない

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

環境　
os win10
ide eclipse
forge1.19.2

以下のチュートリアルを実践中どうしても解決できないバグに会いました
https://moddingtutorials.org/1.19.2/basic-blocks
それ以前のアイテムの追加は正常にできましたがブロックを追加するコードを追加したところこれまで正常に表示されていたアイテムふくめすべてのテクスチャが反映されなくなりました　ブロックの設置や耐久カスタムクラスによる特殊効果は正常に機能します
もう一度別のプロジェクトを立ち上げやり直したところ今度はブロックのテクスチャが反映され　練習のためもう一種類ブロックを追加しようとしたところ同じバグに会いました　ブロック関係のコードやファイルを完全に削除してもこのエラーは継続します

以下はブロック関係を削除したコードですが載せておきます
コードメインクラス

```
package com.example.simplemod;

//import com.example.simplemod.init.BlockInit;
import com.example.simplemod.init.ITMEinit;
import com.mojang.logging.LogUtils;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.world.item.BlockItem;
import net.minecraft.world.item.CreativeModeTab;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.state.BlockBehaviour;
import net.minecraft.world.level.material.Material;
import net.minecraftforge.api.distmarker.Dist;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.IEventBus;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.InterModComms;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLClientSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLCommonSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.InterModEnqueueEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.InterModProcessEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.event.server.ServerStartingEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLJavaModLoadingContext;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.RegistryObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

// The value here should match an entry in the META-INF/mods.toml file
@Mod(SimpleModmain.MODID)
public class SimpleModmain
{
    
    
    // Define mod id in a common place for everything to reference
    public static final String MODID = "simplemod";
    // Directly reference a slf4j logger
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogUtils.getLogger();

    public SimpleModmain() {
        final IEventBus modEventBus = FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus();

        modEventBus.addListener(this::setup);
        ITMEinit.ITEMS.register(modEventBus);
        //BlockInit.BLOCKS.register(modEventBus);
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
    }

    private void setup(final FMLCommonSetupEvent event) {
        
    }
}
```

アイテム追加クラス

```
package com.example.simplemod.init;
import com.mojang.logging.LogUtils;
import com.example.simplemod.SimpleModmain;

import item.SpeedUp;
import item.TeleportStaff;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.world.effect.MobEffectInstance;
import net.minecraft.world.effect.MobEffects;
import net.minecraft.world.food.FoodProperties;
import net.minecraft.world.item.BlockItem;
import net.minecraft.world.item.CreativeModeTab;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.world.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.state.BlockBehaviour;
import net.minecraft.world.level.material.Material;
import net.minecraftforge.api.distmarker.Dist;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.IEventBus;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.InterModComms;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLClientSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLCommonSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.InterModEnqueueEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.InterModProcessEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.event.server.ServerStartingEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLJavaModLoadingContext;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.RegistryObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ITMEinit {
    public static final DeferredRegister<Item> ITEMS = 
            DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS, SimpleModmain.MODID);
    
    //アイテムを追加していきます
    
    // 基本形アイテム
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> oringe_item = ITEMS.register("oringe",
            () -> new Item(new Item.Properties().tab(ModCreativeTab.instance)));
    
    //人肉
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> humun_meat = ITEMS.register("humun_meat",
                () -> new Item(new Item.Properties().tab(ModCreativeTab.instance)
                    .food(new FoodProperties.Builder()
                            .nutrition(4).saturationMod(5)
                            .effect(() -> new MobEffectInstance(MobEffects.FIRE_RESISTANCE, 200, 0), 0.5F)
                            .build())
                    )
            );
    //燃料　スーパー石炭
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> super_fuel = ITEMS.register("super_fuel",
            () -> new Item(new Item.Properties().tab(ModCreativeTab.instance)));
    
    //テレポートアイテム
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> my_teleport = ITEMS.register("my_teleport",
            () -> new TeleportStaff(new Item.Properties().tab(ModCreativeTab.instance)));
    
    //スピードアップ
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> speed_tip = ITEMS.register("speed_tip",
            () -> new SpeedUp(new Item.Properties().tab(ModCreativeTab.instance)));
    
    public static class ModCreativeTab extends CreativeModeTab {
        public static final ModCreativeTab instance = new ModCreativeTab(CreativeModeTab.TABS.length, "firstmod");
        private ModCreativeTab(int index, String label) {
            super(index, label);
        }
        
        
        @Override
        public ItemStack makeIcon() {
            return new ItemStack(oringe_item.get());
        }
    }
}
```

バグとログ　一部文字数制限のため省略しています

```
2023-06-18 20:01:53,572 main WARN Advanced terminal features are not available in this environment
[20:01:53] [main/INFO] [cp.mo.mo.Launcher/MODLAUNCHER]: ModLauncher running: args [--launchTarget, forgeclientuserdev, --version, MOD_DEV, --assetIndex, 1.19, --assetsDir, C:\Users\PC_User\.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\assets, --gameDir, ., --fml.forgeVersion, 43.2.0, --fml.mcVersion, 1.19.2, --fml.forgeGroup, net.minecraftforge, --fml.mcpVersion, 20220805.130853]
[20:01:53] [main/INFO] [cp.mo.mo.Launcher/MODLAUNCHER]: ModLauncher 10.0.9+10.0.9+main.dcd20f30 starting: java version 17.0.7 by Eclipse Adoptium; OS Windows 10 arch amd64 version 10.0
[20:01:53] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.LaunchServiceHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found launch services [fmlclientdev,forgeclient,minecraft,forgegametestserverdev,fmlserveruserdev,fmlclient,fmldatauserdev,forgeserverdev,forgeserveruserdev,forgeclientdev,forgeclientuserdev,forgeserver,forgedatadev,fmlserver,fmlclientuserdev,fmlserverdev,forgedatauserdev,testharness,forgegametestserveruserdev]

文字数制限のため関係なさそうな部分を省略


[20:01:55] [main/INFO] [cp.mo.mo.LaunchServiceHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Launching target 'forgeclientuserdev' with arguments [--version, MOD_DEV, --gameDir, ., --assetsDir, C:\Users\PC_User\.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\assets, --assetIndex, 1.19]
[20:01:55] [main/DEBUG] [mixin/]: Error cleaning class output directory: .mixin.out
[20:01:55] [main/DEBUG] [mixin/]: Preparing mixins for MixinEnvironment[DEFAULT]
[20:01:55] [main/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.lo.InternalLoggerFactory/]: Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
[20:01:55] [main/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.ResourceLeakDetector/]: -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
[20:01:55] [main/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.ResourceLeakDetector/]: -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
[20:01:56] [main/DEBUG] [os.ut.FileUtil/]: No oshi.properties file found from ClassLoader cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformingClassLoader@52bf7bf6
[20:01:56] [main/DEBUG] [os.ut.FileUtil/]: No oshi.architecture.properties file found from ClassLoader cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformingClassLoader@52bf7bf6
[20:01:57] [pool-3-thread-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.tr.CoreModBaseTransformer/COREMOD]: Transforming net/minecraft/world/level/levelgen/structure/Structure
[20:01:57] [pool-3-thread-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.tr.CoreModBaseTransformer/COREMOD]: Transforming net/minecraft/world/level/block/LiquidBlock
[20:01:57] [pool-3-thread-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.tr.CoreModBaseTransformer/COREMOD]: Transforming net/minecraft/world/level/block/StairBlock
[20:01:57] [pool-3-thread-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.tr.CoreModBaseTransformer/COREMOD]: Transforming net/minecraft/world/level/block/FlowerPotBlock
[20:01:58] [pool-3-thread-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.tr.CoreModBaseTransformer/COREMOD]: Transforming net/minecraft/world/item/ItemStack
[20:01:59] [pool-3-thread-1/INFO] [minecraft/DataFixers]: Building unoptimized datafixer
[20:02:00] [pool-3-thread-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.tr.CoreModBaseTransformer/COREMOD]: Transforming net/minecraft/world/level/biome/Biome
[20:02:00] [pool-3-thread-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.tr.CoreModBaseTransformer/COREMOD]: Transforming net/minecraft/world/item/BucketItem
[20:02:00] [pool-3-thread-1/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.tr.CoreModBaseTransformer/COREMOD]: Transforming net/minecraft/world/effect/MobEffectInstance
[20:02:01] [Render thread/WARN] [minecraft/VanillaPackResources]: Assets URL 'union:/C:/Users/PC_User/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/minecraft_user_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.19.2-43.2.0_mapped_official_1.19.2/forge-1.19.2-43.2.0_mapped_official_1.19.2-recomp.jar%23188!/assets/.mcassetsroot' uses unexpected schema
[20:02:01] [Render thread/WARN] [minecraft/VanillaPackResources]: Assets URL 'union:/C:/Users/PC_User/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/minecraft_user_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.19.2-43.2.0_mapped_official_1.19.2/forge-1.19.2-43.2.0_mapped_official_1.19.2-recomp.jar%23188!/data/.mcassetsroot' uses unexpected schema
[20:02:01] [Render thread/INFO] [mojang/YggdrasilAuthenticationService]: Environment: authHost='https://authserver.mojang.com', accountsHost='https://api.mojang.com', sessionHost='https://sessionserver.mojang.com', servicesHost='https://api.minecraftservices.com', name='PROD'
[20:02:01] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/Minecraft]: Setting user: Dev
[20:02:01] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/Minecraft]: Backend library: LWJGL version 3.3.1 build 7
[20:02:01] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.ForgeI18n/CORE]: Loading I18N data entries: 5641
[20:02:01] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ModWorkManager/LOADING]: Using 24 threads for parallel mod-loading
[20:02:01] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ja.FMLJavaModLanguageProvider/LOADING]: Loading FMLModContainer from classloader cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformingClassLoader@52bf7bf6 - got cpw.mods.cl.ModuleClassLoader@4a6c18ad
[20:02:01] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ja.FMLModContainer/LOADING]: Creating FMLModContainer instance for com.example.simplemod.SimpleModmain
[20:02:01] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ja.FMLJavaModLanguageProvider/LOADING]: Loading FMLModContainer from classloader cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformingClassLoader@52bf7bf6 - got cpw.mods.cl.ModuleClassLoader@4a6c18ad
[20:02:01] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ja.FMLModContainer/LOADING]: Creating FMLModContainer instance for net.minecraftforge.common.ForgeMod
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.ve.fo.ForgeVersion/CORE]: Forge Version package package net.minecraftforge.versions.forge, Forge, version 43.2 from cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformingClassLoader@52bf7bf6
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.ve.fo.ForgeVersion/CORE]: Found Forge version 43.2.0
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.ve.fo.ForgeVersion/CORE]: Found Forge spec 43.2
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.ve.fo.ForgeVersion/CORE]: Found Forge group net.minecraftforge
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.ve.mc.MCPVersion/CORE]: MCP Version package package net.minecraftforge.versions.mcp, Minecraft, version 1.19.2 from cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformingClassLoader@52bf7bf6
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.ve.mc.MCPVersion/CORE]: Found MC version information 1.19.2
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.ve.mc.MCPVersion/CORE]: Found MCP version information 20220805.130853
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/INFO] [ne.mi.co.ForgeMod/FORGEMOD]: Forge mod loading, version 43.2.0, for MC 1.19.2 with MCP 20220805.130853
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/INFO] [ne.mi.co.MinecraftForge/FORGE]: MinecraftForge v43.2.0 Initialized
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ja.AutomaticEventSubscriber/LOADING]: Attempting to inject @EventBusSubscriber classes into the eventbus for simplemod
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent0/]: -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent0/]: Java version: 17
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent0/]: sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent0/]: sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent0/]: sun.misc.Unsafe.storeFence: available
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent0/]: java.nio.Buffer.address: available
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent0/]: direct buffer constructor: unavailable
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled
   at io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil.trySetAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:31) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$5.run(PlatformDependent0.java:287) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318) ~[?:?] {}
   at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:281) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid(PlatformDependent.java:294) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:88) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at io.netty.util.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:34) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at io.netty.util.AttributeKey$1.<init>(AttributeKey.java:27) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at io.netty.util.AttributeKey.<clinit>(AttributeKey.java:27) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at net.minecraftforge.network.NetworkConstants.<clinit>(NetworkConstants.java:34) ~[forge-1.19.2-43.2.0_mapped_official_1.19.2-recomp.jar%23187%23194!/:?] {re:classloading}
   at net.minecraftforge.common.ForgeMod.<init>(ForgeMod.java:436) ~[forge-1.19.2-43.2.0_mapped_official_1.19.2-recomp.jar%23187%23194!/:?] {re:classloading}
   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?] {}
   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?] {}
   at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?] {}
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?] {}
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?] {}
   at net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:68) ~[javafmllanguage-1.19.2-43.2.0.jar%23189!/:?] {}
   at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModContainer.lambda$buildTransitionHandler$10(ModContainer.java:121) ~[fmlcore-1.19.2-43.2.0.jar%23192!/:?] {}
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) [?:?] {}
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796) [?:?] {}
   at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373) [?:?] {}
   at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182) [?:?] {}
   at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655) [?:?] {}
   at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622) [?:?] {}
   at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165) [?:?] {}
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent0/]: java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent0/]: jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$7 (in module io.netty.common) cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to module io.netty.common
   at jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392) ~[?:?] {}
   at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674) ~[?:?] {}
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:560) ~[?:?] {}
   at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$7.run(PlatformDependent0.java:409) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318) ~[?:?] {}
   at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:400) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid(PlatformDependent.java:294) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:88) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at io.netty.util.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:34) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at io.netty.util.AttributeKey$1.<init>(AttributeKey.java:27) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at io.netty.util.AttributeKey.<clinit>(AttributeKey.java:27) ~[netty-common-4.1.77.Final.jar%23146!/:4.1.77.Final] {}
   at net.minecraftforge.network.NetworkConstants.<clinit>(NetworkConstants.java:34) ~[forge-1.19.2-43.2.0_mapped_official_1.19.2-recomp.jar%23187%23194!/:?] {re:classloading}
   at net.minecraftforge.common.ForgeMod.<init>(ForgeMod.java:436) ~[forge-1.19.2-43.2.0_mapped_official_1.19.2-recomp.jar%23187%23194!/:?] {re:classloading}
   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?] {}
   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?] {}
   at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?] {}
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?] {}
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?] {}
   at net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:68) ~[javafmllanguage-1.19.2-43.2.0.jar%23189!/:?] {}
   at net.minecraftforge.fml.ModContainer.lambda$buildTransitionHandler$10(ModContainer.java:121) ~[fmlcore-1.19.2-43.2.0.jar%23192!/:?] {}
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) [?:?] {}
   at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796) [?:?] {}
   at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373) [?:?] {}
   at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182) [?:?] {}
   at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655) [?:?] {}
   at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622) [?:?] {}
   at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165) [?:?] {}
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent0/]: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): unavailable
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent/]: sun.misc.Unsafe: available
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent/]: maxDirectMemory: 17163091968 bytes (maybe)
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent/]: -Dio.netty.tmpdir: C:\Users\PC_User\AppData\Local\Temp (java.io.tmpdir)
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent/]: -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent/]: Platform: Windows
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent/]: -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: -1 bytes
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent/]: -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.CleanerJava9/]: java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [io.ne.ut.in.PlatformDependent/]: -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.ForgeMod/FORGEMOD]: Loading Network data for FML net version: FML3
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigTracker/CONFIG]: Config file forge-client.toml for forge tracking
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigTracker/CONFIG]: Config file forge-server.toml for forge tracking
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigTracker/CONFIG]: Config file forge-common.toml for forge tracking
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ja.AutomaticEventSubscriber/LOADING]: Attempting to inject @EventBusSubscriber classes into the eventbus for forge
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ja.AutomaticEventSubscriber/LOADING]: Auto-subscribing net.minecraftforge.common.ForgeSpawnEggItem$CommonHandler to MOD
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ja.AutomaticEventSubscriber/LOADING]: Auto-subscribing net.minecraftforge.common.ForgeSpawnEggItem$ColorRegisterHandler to MOD
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ja.AutomaticEventSubscriber/LOADING]: Auto-subscribing net.minecraftforge.client.model.data.ModelDataManager to FORGE
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ja.AutomaticEventSubscriber/LOADING]: Auto-subscribing net.minecraftforge.client.ForgeHooksClient$ClientEvents to MOD
[20:02:01] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.ja.AutomaticEventSubscriber/LOADING]: Auto-subscribing net.minecraftforge.client.ClientForgeMod to MOD
[20:02:02] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.ca.CapabilityManager/CAPABILITIES]: Attempting to automatically register: Lnet/minecraftforge/energy/IEnergyStorage;
[20:02:02] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.ca.CapabilityManager/CAPABILITIES]: Attempting to automatically register: Lnet/minecraftforge/fluids/capability/IFluidHandler;
[20:02:02] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.ca.CapabilityManager/CAPABILITIES]: Attempting to automatically register: Lnet/minecraftforge/fluids/capability/IFluidHandlerItem;
[20:02:02] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.ca.CapabilityManager/CAPABILITIES]: Attempting to automatically register: Lnet/minecraftforge/items/IItemHandler;
[20:02:02] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.cl.lo.ClientModLoader/CORE]: Generating PackInfo named mod:simplemod for mod file C:\Users\PC_User\eclipse-workspace\simple_mod2\bin\main
[20:02:02] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.cl.lo.ClientModLoader/CORE]: Generating PackInfo named mod:forge for mod file /
[20:02:02] [Render thread/INFO] [ne.mi.ga.ForgeGameTestHooks/]: Enabled Gametest Namespaces: [examplemod]
[20:02:02] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/ReloadableResourceManager]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default, Mod Resources
[20:02:02] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigTracker/CONFIG]: Loading configs type CLIENT
[20:02:02] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigFileTypeHandler/CONFIG]: Built TOML config for C:\Users\PC_User\eclipse-workspace\simple_mod2\run\config\forge-client.toml
[20:02:02] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigFileTypeHandler/CONFIG]: Loaded TOML config file C:\Users\PC_User\eclipse-workspace\simple_mod2\run\config\forge-client.toml
[20:02:02] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigFileTypeHandler/CONFIG]: Watching TOML config file C:\Users\PC_User\eclipse-workspace\simple_mod2\run\config\forge-client.toml for changes
[20:02:02] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.ForgeConfig/FORGEMOD]: Loaded forge config file forge-client.toml
[20:02:02] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigTracker/CONFIG]: Loading configs type COMMON
[20:02:02] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigFileTypeHandler/CONFIG]: Built TOML config for C:\Users\PC_User\eclipse-workspace\simple_mod2\run\config\forge-common.toml
[20:02:02] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigFileTypeHandler/CONFIG]: Loaded TOML config file C:\Users\PC_User\eclipse-workspace\simple_mod2\run\config\forge-common.toml
[20:02:02] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.co.ConfigFileTypeHandler/CONFIG]: Watching TOML config file C:\Users\PC_User\eclipse-workspace\simple_mod2\run\config\forge-common.toml for changes
[20:02:02] [modloading-worker-0/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.ForgeConfig/FORGEMOD]: Loaded forge config file forge-common.toml
[20:02:03] [Forge Version Check/INFO] [ne.mi.fm.VersionChecker/]: [forge] Starting version check at https://files.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/promotions_slim.json
[20:02:04] [Forge Version Check/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.VersionChecker/]: [forge] Received version check data:
{
 "homepage": "https://files.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/",
 "promos": {文字数制限のため省略
 }
}
[20:02:04] [Forge Version Check/INFO] [ne.mi.fm.VersionChecker/]: [forge] Found status: UP_TO_DATE Current: 43.2.0 Target: null
[20:02:06] [Worker-Main-20/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to load model: 'simplemod:oringe#inventory' referenced from: simplemod:oringe#inventory: java.io.FileNotFoundException: simplemod:models/item/oringe.json
[20:02:06] [Worker-Main-20/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to load model: 'simplemod:humun_meat#inventory' referenced from: simplemod:humun_meat#inventory: java.io.FileNotFoundException: simplemod:models/item/humun_meat.json
[20:02:06] [Worker-Main-20/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to load model: 'simplemod:super_fuel#inventory' referenced from: simplemod:super_fuel#inventory: java.io.FileNotFoundException: simplemod:models/item/super_fuel.json
[20:02:06] [Worker-Main-20/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to load model: 'simplemod:my_teleport#inventory' referenced from: simplemod:my_teleport#inventory: java.io.FileNotFoundException: simplemod:models/item/my_teleport.json
[20:02:06] [Worker-Main-20/WARN] [minecraft/ModelBakery]: Unable to load model: 'simplemod:speed_tip#inventory' referenced from: simplemod:speed_tip#inventory: java.io.FileNotFoundException: simplemod:models/item/speed_tip.json
[20:02:07] [Render thread/DEBUG] [ne.mi.co.ForgeI18n/CORE]: Loading I18N data entries: 5874
[20:02:07] [Render thread/WARN] [minecraft/SoundEngine]: Missing sound for event: minecraft:item.goat_horn.play
[20:02:07] [Render thread/WARN] [minecraft/SoundEngine]: Missing sound for event: minecraft:entity.goat.screaming.horn_break
[20:02:08] [Render thread/INFO] [mojang/Library]: OpenAL initialized on device OpenAL Soft on BenQ GW2283 (NVIDIA High Definition Audio)
[20:02:08] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/SoundEngine]: Sound engine started
[20:02:08] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 1024x512x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/blocks.png-atlas
[20:02:08] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 256x128x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/signs.png-atlas
[20:02:08] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 512x512x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/banner_patterns.png-atlas
[20:02:08] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 512x512x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/shield_patterns.png-atlas
[20:02:08] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 256x256x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/chest.png-atlas
[20:02:08] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 512x256x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/beds.png-atlas
[20:02:08] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 512x256x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/shulker_boxes.png-atlas
[20:02:08] [Render thread/WARN] [minecraft/ShaderInstance]: Shader rendertype_entity_translucent_emissive could not find sampler named Sampler2 in the specified shader program.
[20:02:09] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 256x256x0 minecraft:textures/atlas/particles.png-atlas
[20:02:09] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 256x256x0 minecraft:textures/atlas/paintings.png-atlas
[20:02:09] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/TextureAtlas]: Created: 128x128x0 minecraft:textures/atlas/mob_effects.png-atlas
[20:02:09] [Realms Notification Availability checker #1/INFO] [mojang/RealmsClient]: Could not authorize you against Realms server: Invalid session id
[20:02:13] [Render thread/INFO] [minecraft/Minecraft]: Stopping!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eclipseの機能の問題でした　デフォルトではパッケージプレゼンテーションがフラットになっていたためassetsあたりが非常にみずらくなっておりその解決をchatgptに聞いたらビルドパス＞除外を行えと言われ　それを信じたせいでした